# Looking for a material so I can make ABS parts with rubber grips and feet

Tags: abs, dual-nozzle

Looking for something that offers a lot of friction in contact with human skin or when sitting on the surface of a table.

I was curious if any of the rubber/soft materials would be compatible with ABS so I could print them together using a dual-head setup?

Comment: Why not just use some [rubber feet](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-Sale-100PCS-Self-Adhesive-Rubber-Feet-Clear-Semicircle-Bumpers-Door-Buffer-Pad/32668740126.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_7,searchweb201602_4_10057_10056_10055_10037_10049_10033_10059_10032_10058_10017_405_404_10040_10060,searchweb201603_6&btsid=67fc3d45-9040-406d-a9db-8beb283bb42c)?

Answer (score 5):

Ninjaflex dual-extrudes great with ABS. I've done a fair amount of NF/ABS dualstrusion. Frankly, any TPU will probably work, since molten polyurethane sticks to practically anything.

The main challenge is ooze control since TPUs tend to ooze a lot. You're going to want to use a printing temp on the low end of the range for the flexible filament, and use some sort of wiper wall structure.

Another issue you might run into is re-priming the flexible filament after an extended idle time. It helps to use a large purge structure to ensure the nozzle gets re-primed fully. Don't use an excessively large toolchange retraction distance -- this will make it more likely that the flexible filament jams during reprime.

The best way to accomplish the above will depend on your slicer. Simplify3D is a good choice since it has good dualstrusion wiper and purge functions. Other slicers can be made to work as well.

Comment: Ninjaflex is hard to print. I have had little success. That said there are some guys at the local hackerspace selling https://flexionextruder.com/ Combine that, with a duel headed extruder and you can proably do it in one go. 

Also there are other variants of ninjaflex from the same company that have more and less give.